# Scala vs Java Streaming: Scala prints nothing, Java works

Tags: java, scala, rx-java, reactive-programming, akka-stream

I'm doing a comparison between Scala vs Java Reactive Spec implementations using [akka-stream](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/current/scala.html) and [RxJava](http://reactivex.io), respectively. My use case is a simplistic `grep`: Given a directory, a file filter and a search text, I look in that directory for all matching files that have the text. I then stream the (filename -> matching line) pair.
This works fine for Java but for Scala, nothing is printed. There's no exception but no output either.
The data for the test is downloaded from the internet but as you can see, the code can easily be tested with any local directory as well.

**Scala**:

```
object Transformer {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("transformer")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val executionContext: ExecutionContext = {
    implicitly
  }

  import collection.JavaConverters._

  def run(path: String, text: String, fileFilter: String) = {
    Source.fromIterator { () =>
      Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(path), fileFilter).iterator().asScala
    }.map(p => {
      val lines = io.Source.fromFile(p.toFile).getLines().filter(_.contains(text)).map(_.trim).to[ImmutableList]
      (p, lines)
    })
      .runWith(Sink.foreach(e => println(s"${e._1} -> ${e._2}")))
  }
}
```

**Java**:

```
public class Transformer {
    public static void run(String path, String text, String fileFilter) {
        Observable.from(files(path, fileFilter)).flatMap(p -> {
            try {
                return Observable.from((Iterable<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>>) Files.lines(p)
                        .filter(line -> line.contains(text))
                        .map(String::trim)
                        .collect(collectingAndThen(groupingBy(pp -> p.toAbsolutePath().toString()), Map::entrySet)));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
            }
        }).toBlocking().forEach(e -> System.out.printf("%s -> %s.%n", e.getKey(), e.getValue()));
    }

    private static Iterable<Path> files(String path, String fileFilter) {
        try {
            return Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(path), fileFilter);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

**Unit test** using Scala Test:

```
class TransformerSpec extends FlatSpec with Matchers {
  "Transformer" should "extract temperature" in {
    Transformer.run(NoaaClient.currentConditionsPath(), "temp_f", "*.xml")
  }

  "Java Transformer" should "extract temperature" in {
    JavaTransformer.run(JavaNoaaClient.currentConditionsPath(false), "temp_f", "*.xml")
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't know about akka streams, but in your Java version you're converting the Observable `toBlocking()` so your execution flow won't finish until the chain completes, but it looks like the Akka version is all running async.  Could this merely be the fact your VM/test terminates before the Akka version gets a chance to complete?

Comment: Have you tried including a print statement here and there in the scala version and see if it actually runs?

Comment: @MrWiggles You were close, see my answer below. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Dang, I forgot that `Source` returns a `Future`, which means the flow never ran. @MrWiggles' comment gave me a hint. The following Scala code produces equivalent result as the Java version.

**Note**: The code in my question didn't close the `DirectoryStream`which, for directories with a large number of files, caused a `java.io.IOException: Too many open files in system`. The code below closes the resources up properly.

```
def run(path: String, text: String, fileFilter: String) = {
  val files = Files.newDirectoryStream(Paths.get(path), fileFilter)

  val future = Source(files.asScala.toList).map(p => {
    val lines = io.Source.fromFile(p.toFile).getLines().filter(_.contains(text)).map(_.trim).to[ImmutableList]
    (p, lines)
    })
    .filter(!_._2.isEmpty)
    .runWith(Sink.foreach(e => println(s"${e._1} -> ${e._2}")))

  Await.result(future, 10.seconds)

  files.close

  true // for testing
}
```